# JSP Servlet to retrieve(display) web pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am writing a servlet in JSP page to display the requested webpage. I have done fair bit of "googling" and most of them suggested of using BufferedReader. Below I have the code that gets the requested url from the JSP page and the servlet displays the page.

However, while running this I am getting blank from the servlet. Could anyone suggest me what wrong I have been doing in this code?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String server = request.getParameter("browsebox");

        URL url = new URL(server);
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(a);
        // String output= a.toString();
        //System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are very, very close. But why are you printing the target web page on console rather than sending it back to the client? Try this for starters:

```
response.getWriter().println(a);
```

Once you overcome that problem think how can you avoid loading the whole target web page first to a `String` and then sending it back. What about reading target web page line by line or byte by byte and sending it immediately? Not only the client will receive partial response earlier, but you will save a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have commented my very last line your suggestion added. But still no output. the result is complete blank still :(.

Comment: @user1382329: can you debug or print what are the contents of `a` variable before you `println()` it to servlet response?

Comment: system.out.println(a); gave no output at the console. I explicitly pass url eg. "http://www.stackoverflow.com" into the url but still not able to get any output.

Comment: @user1382329 - Are you seeing an error? If yes, what is it? Check if you passed url with protocol or not? ex. `http://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I am not seeing any error report(in the console). I am getting blank(white)page after I run the servlet. Yes, I did pass url with the protocol.

Comment: @user1382329: `a` is an empty string? I just tested the exact same code by entering `http://localhost:8080/someServlet?browsebox=http://stackoverflow.com` and it displays beautiful SO main page on my computer. On the other hand using not-existing domain yields 500 with nice stack trace in the browser. Focus on retrieving the page, debug the `while` loop. Also try `IOUtils.copy()` from Apache Commons. As far as I can see your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the PrintWriter object from the response object.

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println(<value>);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println(a);
```

it should work. 
Still if it is not working try,

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println(a);`
out.flush();
```